# HTML carousel - ie7 zooming issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have made a carousel of items using the Malsup Cycle plugin. It all works great except when zooming in IE7. The borders on the list items seem to fly off while the text remains fixed or hidden by other elements.

[image: Example]

The HTML contains some extra containers to make vertical alignment in IE7 work the way we need it. Otherwise the HTML fairly standard. Fiddle below

`<li>
                        <div class="outerContainer" style="width:55px;"> <!-- example of a specific width applied -->
                        <div class="innerContainer">
                        <div class="element">
                        Incoming Arrival</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>`

http://jsfiddle.net/QypfY/

I know JS Fiddle doesnt work in IE7 but perhaps someone has an idea of whats going wrong. I tried changing the absolute positioning to relative but i still get the same issue.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Note that you can show the output of the Fiddle in IE7 by adding `show` at the end of the fiddle URI. [http://jsfiddle.net/QypfY/show](http://jsfiddle.net/QypfY/show).